# Opening a GStreamer pipeline from OpenCV with VideoWriter

Tags: c++, opencv, video, gstreamer

I am capturing and processing video frames with OpenCV, and I would like to write them as a h265 video file. I am struggling to get a proper Gstreamer pipeline to work from OpenCV.

Gstreamer works fine by itself. In particular, I am able to run this command, which encodes video very quickly (thanks to GPU acceleration) and saves it to a mkv file:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc num-buffers=90 ! 'video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)640, height=(int)480' ! omxh265enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv
```

Now I would like to do the same thing from within my OpenCV application. My code is something like:

```
Mat img_vid = Mat(1024, 1024, CV_8UC3);

VideoWriter video;
video.open("appsrc ! autovideoconvert ! omxh265enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv", 0, (double)25, cv::Size(1024, 1024), true);

if (!video.isOpened()) {
   printf("can't create writer\n");
   return -1;
}

while ( ... ) {

   // Capture frame into img_vid => That works fine

   video.write(img_vid);

   ...
}
```

At first sight, this seems to work, but what it does is it creates file *named* `"appsrc ! autovideoconvert ! omxh265enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv"` and fills it with uncompressed video frames, **completely ignoring the fact that this is a Gstreamer pipeline**.

I have tried other pipelines, but they result in a variety of errors:

```
video.open("appsrc ! autovideoconvert ! omxh264enc ! 'video/x-h264, streamformat=(string)byte-stream' ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location=test.mp4 -e", 0, (double)25, cv::Size(1024, 1024), true);
```

Which results in:

> (Test:5533): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_make_from_uri:
>   assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed OpenCV Error: Unspecified
>   error (GStreamer: cannot find appsrc in manual pipeline ) in
>   CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file
>   /home/ubuntu/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 1363
>   VIDEOIO(cvCreateVideoWriter_GStreamer(filename, fourcc, fps,
>   frameSize, is_color)): raised OpenCV exception:
>
> /home/ubuntu/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1363: error:
>   (-2) GStreamer: cannot find appsrc in manual pipeline  in function
>   CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open

I also tried the simple:

```
video.open("appsrc ! autovideosink", 0, (double)25, cv::Size(1024, 1024), true);
```

which yields:

> GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module appsrc0
>   reported: Internal data flow error.

I am using OpenCV 3.1 with Gstreamer support. The hardware is a Jetson TX1 with L4T 24.2.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem before. Since the pipe/file name ends with `.mkv`, OpenCV interprets it as a video file instead of a pipe.

You can try ending it with a dummy spacing like after `mkv`

```
video.open("appsrc ! autovideoconvert ! omxh265enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv ", 0, (double)25, cv::Size(1024, 1024), true);
```

or with a dummy property like

```
video.open("appsrc ! autovideoconvert ! omxh265enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test.mkv sync=false", 0, (double)25, cv::Size(1024, 1024), true);
```

Comment: It works!!!! Oh man, thank you so much. I've spent so much time on this and had no idea what was wrong...

Comment: Hi sir! How can I write/push the images to the RTMP pipeline, not to a file?

Comment: This didn't work for me. It is still writing to a file which name is the entire Gstreamer pipeline, whether or not there is a space or a dummy property at the end (GStreamer 1.12.4, Mac OSX 10.13.3).

Comment: @SimonGarnier there is another overload to `VideoWriter::open()`  function with `apiPreference` parameter. You might want to try that with `cv::CAP_GSTREAMER` as `apiPreference` parameter. Here's a link to the documentation of the function: https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#a808ee7d60c58af071035a19e396bfa91

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler Yep, that did it. Thanks!