# OpenCV 3.4.3 - GStream not called when VideoWriting

Tags: file, opencv, gstreamer, pipeline, x264

I'd like to succeed writing a file with OpenCV encoding with GStreamer.

**Thus I'm using the code :**

```
VideoWriter.open("appsrc ! autovideoconvert ! omxh264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test2.mkv sync=false",
//cv::CAP_GSTREAMER, //set or not, I get the same problem
0, (double)25, //fourcc, fps
cv::Size(1024, 1024), 
true);
```

**And my problem :**

A video file called *appsrc ! autovideoconvert ! omxh264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test2.mkv sync=false* is created (rather than *test2.mkv*), and it is empty. The same problem is corrected and seems to work in the following thread, without any effect for me : [Opening a GStreamer pipeline from OpenCV with VideoWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412797/opening-a-gstreamer-pipeline-from-opencv-with-videowriter)

**I tried, without success :**

- Add quotes to the file name test2 :
  "appsrc ! autovideoconvert ! omxh264enc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=\"test2.mkv\" sync=false" neither
- Encode with different format : .flv rather than .mkv
- Encode with different codec : omxh265enc rather than omxh264en

**I checked :**

- That GStreamer is well compiled with OpenCV ; the CMake of the OpenCV project outputs :

  Video I/O:Video for Windows: YES
  DC1394: NO
  FFMPEG: YES (prebuilt binaries)
  avcodec: YES (ver 57.107.100)
  avformat: YES (ver 57.83.100)
  avutil: YES (ver 55.78.100)
  swscale: YES (ver 4.8.100)
  avresample: YES (ver 3.7.0)
  GStreamer:

  base: YES (ver 1.0)

  video: YES (ver 1.0)

  app: YES (ver 1.0)

  riff: YES (ver 1.0)

  pbutils: YES (ver 1.0)

  DirectShow: YES

  Media Foundation: YES
- That FFMpeg is installed on my computer ; for this I used VLC :

  File -> Stream -> Add a file then stream
  New destination : RTP/MPEG Transport Stream
  Profile : Video - H.264 + MP3 (MP4)
  *Then no error happens ; Note : an error occured with Video - H.265 + MP3 
  (MP4), but I'm using omxh264enc in my code, not 265*

I'm struggled :/ Do you have any idea ?
Thanks a lot :)

Have a good day,

Thibaut

**PS - Complete OpenCV CMake output :**

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.17134.0 to target Windows 10.0.17763.
AVX_512F is not supported by C++ compiler

AVX512_SKX is not supported by C++ compiler

Dispatch optimization AVX512_SKX is not available, skipped

libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 1.5.3, BUILD = opencv-3.4.3-libjpeg-turbo

Looking for Mfapi.h

Looking for Mfapi.h - found

found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]

at: E:/OpenCV/3.4.3/build-cuda92-gstreamer/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win

found Intel IPP IW sources: 2017.0.3

at: E:/OpenCV/3.4.3/build-cuda92-gstreamer/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_win

CUDA detected: 9.2

CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;-gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_52,code=sm_52;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-D_FORCE_INLINES

Found apache ant: C:/NVPACK/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant.bat (1.8.2)

Could NOT find Matlab (missing: MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN)

VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file

Caffe: NO

Protobuf: NO

Glog: YES

freetype2: NO

harfbuzz: NO

Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found

No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.

Found installed version of gflags: E:/Git/gflags/BUILD-VS2015

Detected gflags version: 2.2.1

Checking SFM deps... FALSE

Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags

Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp

Tesseract: NO


General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.3 =====================================

Version control: unknown


Extra modules:

Location (extra): E:/OpenCV/3.4.3/opencv_contrib-3.4.3/modules

Version control (extra): unknown


Platform:

Timestamp: 2018-11-07T16:57:18Z

Host: Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64

CMake: 3.12.0-rc2

CMake generator: Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64

CMake build tool: C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe

MSVC: 1900


CPU/HW features:

Baseline: SSE SSE2 SSE3

requested: SSE3

Dispatched code generation: SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2

requested: SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX

SSE4_1 (5 files): + SSSE3 SSE4_1

SSE4_2 (2 files): + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2

FP16 (2 files): + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX

AVX (6 files): + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX

AVX2 (11 files): + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2


C/C++:

Built as dynamic libs?: YES

C++11: YES

C++ Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe (ver 19.0.24215.1)

C++ flags (Release): /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP16 /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG

C++ flags (Debug): /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP16 /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1

C Compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe

C flags (Release): /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /MP16 /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG

C flags (Debug): /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi /MP16 /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1

Linker flags (Release): /machine:x64 /INCREMENTAL:NO

Linker flags (Debug): /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL

ccache: NO

Precompiled headers: YES

Extra dependencies: cudart.lib nppc.lib nppial.lib nppicc.lib nppicom.lib nppidei.lib nppif.lib nppig.lib nppim.lib nppist.lib nppisu.lib nppitc.lib npps.lib cublas.lib cufft.lib -LIBPATH:C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.2/lib/x64

3rdparty dependencies:


OpenCV modules:

To be built: aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann fuzzy hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking ts video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto

Disabled: js world

Disabled by dependency: -

Unavailable: cnn_3dobj cvv freetype hdf matlab ovis python2 python3 sfm viz

Applications: tests perf_tests apps

Documentation: NO

Non-free algorithms: NO


Windows RT support: NO


GUI:

Win32 UI: YES

VTK support: NO


Media I/O:

ZLib: build (ver 1.2.11)

JPEG: build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)

WEBP: build (ver encoder: 0x020e)

PNG: build (ver 1.6.34)

TIFF: build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)

JPEG 2000: build (ver 1.900.1)

OpenEXR: build (ver 1.7.1)

HDR: YES

SUNRASTER: YES

PXM: YES


Video I/O:

Video for Windows: YES

DC1394: NO

FFMPEG: YES (prebuilt binaries)

avcodec: YES (ver 57.107.100)

avformat: YES (ver 57.83.100)

avutil: YES (ver 55.78.100)

swscale: YES (ver 4.8.100)

avresample: YES (ver 3.7.0)

GStreamer:

base: YES (ver 1.0)

video: YES (ver 1.0)

app: YES (ver 1.0)

riff: YES (ver 1.0)

pbutils: YES (ver 1.0)

DirectShow: YES

Media Foundation: YES


Parallel framework: Concurrency


Trace: YES (with Intel ITT)


Other third-party libraries:

Intel IPP: 2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]

at: E:/OpenCV/3.4.3/build-cuda92-gstreamer/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win

Intel IPP IW: sources (2017.0.3)

at: E:/OpenCV/3.4.3/build-cuda92-gstreamer/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_win

Custom HAL: NO

Protobuf: build (3.5.1)


NVIDIA CUDA: YES (ver 9.2, CUFFT CUBLAS NVCUVID)

NVIDIA GPU arch: 30 35 37 50 52 60 61 70

NVIDIA PTX archs:


OpenCL: YES (no extra features)

Include path: E:/OpenCV/3.4.3/opencv-3.4.3/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2

Link libraries: Dynamic load


Python (for build): C:/ProgramData/Miniconda3/python.exe


Java:

ant: C:/NVPACK/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.8.2)

JNI: C:/NVPACK/jdk1.8.0_77/include C:/NVPACK/jdk1.8.0_77/include/win32 C:/NVPACK/jdk1.8.0_77/include

Java wrappers: YES

Java tests: YES


Matlab: NO


Install to: E:/OpenCV/3.4.3/build/install

-----------------------------------------------------------------


Configuring done
```

Comment: *Hey guys,

(sorry, it disapeared after copy-pasting my question draft to stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've eventually found the problem's origin.

By stepping into VideoWriter::open(...) I finally noticed that std::vector backends did not contain any element with "id=CAP_GSTREAMER" -> it did not correctly compile with OpenCV. By investigating more, I discovered it was because I compiled with the x86 version of Gstreamer by mistake (whereas I was building OpenCV for x64).

Have a good day,

Thibaut